# Hide placeholder value with JQuery

Tags: jquery, placeholder

I have a lot of templates with some text input like this:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="Keywords" name="keywords" id="keywords">
```

The client asked me to hide the placeholder value (Keywords in the example) when the user click on the field. I don't know how to do this with JS and JQuery. Is there a way to make this happen with a crossbrowser solution?

Comment: I recommend pushing back on this one. Different browsers hide placeholder text at different times — some when the field is clicked in, some when the user starts to type in it — consistency with how placeholders work for the user on other sites is a virtue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:  { check it if cross browser }

[http://jsfiddle.net/MDhtj/1](http://jsfiddle.net/MDhtj/1/)

```
$('input[placeholder]').on('focus', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('placeholder', $this.prop('placeholder')).removeAttr('placeholder')
}).on('blur', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.prop('placeholder', $this.data('placeholder'));
});
```